# Azurerm Data Source returns not found for everything

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

In a Terraform workspace I'm connecting to Azure using a Service Principal that is a Contributor at the Subscription level.

If I create a resource group in Terraform and then create and access it via a data source it works fine.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg_0" {
  location = "uksouth"
  name     = "MyTestResourceGroup34545"
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name = "MyTestResourceGroup34545"
}

output "id" {
  value = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.id
}
```

After creating the resource group in this manner I can create a new Terraform workspace and in there just use the data source and output config and it will correctly access the resource group.

If however I create a resource group in the Portal or by some other means, and attempt to acess that via a data source

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name = "CreatedSomewhereElse"
}

output "id" {
  value = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.id
}
```

Then I get an error

```
PS C:\Home\Workspaces\Azure\TerraformFunctionApp\infra\environment> tf apply
data.azurerm_resource_group.example: Reading...
╷
│ Error: Error: Resource Group "CreatedSomewhereElse" was not found
│
│   with data.azurerm_resource_group.example,
│   on main.tf line 28, in data "azurerm_resource_group" "example":
│   28: data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
```

I have the same issue no matter what type of resource it is I'm trying to access, resource group, storage account, anything.

This doesn't make any sense to me. I'm guessing something must be wrong with my configuration but I can't think what.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. It wasn't I'd completely given up and was trying to delete the resource group that I was testing all this in that I realised the name of the resource group had a typo and so wasn't what I thought it was.

That's an entire morning of my life I won't get back.